# n_diff_pfxNN does not match index unique count in MySQL8

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-8.0

My table data is as follows

```sql
create table employees
(
    emp_no int not null primary key,
    birth_date datetime not null,
    first_name varchar(14) not null,
    last_name varchar(16) not null,
    gender enum('M', 'F') not null,
    hire_date datetime not null,
    full_name varchar(50) as (concat(`first_name`,_utf8mb4' ',`last_name`))
)
collate=utf8mb4_general_ci;

create index ix_firstname
    on employees (first_name);

create index ix_fullname
    on employees (full_name);

create index ix_gender_birthdate
    on employees (gender, birth_date);

create index ix_hiredate
    on employees (hire_date);

create index ix_lastname_firstname
    on employees (last_name, first_name);

create definer = root@localhost trigger on_delete
    before delete
    on employees
    for each row
    BEGIN
         DELETE FROM salaries WHERE emp_no=OLD.emp_no; 
       END;
```

And this table have `300,204` rows.

I set this table as 'STATS_PERSISTENT=1' to use it as permanent statistics, and I checked the results and found something strange.
I think this value(`PRIMARY.n_diff_pfx01`) should match the number of rows in the table.
because this table has a Primary Key(`emp_no`) that has a unique value.
I read this [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-persistent-stats.html) but I couldn't find the result I wanted.

```
//Primary.n_diff_pfx01 is 299,101 but table row count is 300,024
+-------------+----------+------------+-------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------+
|database_name|table_name|index_name  |last_update        |stat_name   |stat_value|sample_size|stat_description                 |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------+
|employees    |employees |PRIMARY     |2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_diff_pfx01|299101    |20         |emp_no                           |
|employees    |employees |PRIMARY     |2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_leaf_pages|965       |NULL       |Number of leaf pages in the index|
|employees    |employees |ix_firstname|2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_diff_pfx01|1279      |20         |first_name                       |
|employees    |employees |ix_firstname|2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_diff_pfx02|299286    |20         |first_name,emp_no                |
|employees    |employees |ix_firstname|2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_leaf_pages|496       |NULL       |Number of leaf pages in the index|
|employees    |employees |ix_firstname|2022-10-12 22:44:12|size        |609       |NULL       |Number of pages in the index     |
|employees    |employees |ix_fullname |2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_diff_pfx01|280729    |20         |full_name                        |
|employees    |employees |ix_fullname |2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_diff_pfx02|296383    |20         |full_name,emp_no                 |
|employees    |employees |ix_fullname |2022-10-12 22:44:12|n_leaf_pages|478       |NULL       |Number of leaf pages in the index|
|employees    |employees |ix_fullname |2022-10-12 22:44:12|size        |609       |NULL       |Number of pages in the index     |
+-------------+----------+------------+-------------------+------------+----------+-----------+---------------------------------+
```